# Oracle 11g, orapwd.exe do no open

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

when I try to open file orapwd.exe, it opens and immediately shuts down
Also, I tried to open it with admin rights, but nothing changed.

[image]

What you could recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is used to create a password file. Run it from the operating system command prompt; navigate to that directory (to be sure which file you'll actually run). For example:

```
d:
    
cd d:\oracle\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin

orapwd file=orapwSID password=oracle entries=5
```